# How to calculate Bayesian probability between two variables?

Tags: probability, correlation, bayesian

I have 1000 data for two continuous variables (pressure and temperature). I'd like to calculate Bayesian probability between two variables.

In other words, I would like to determine probability that temperature will increase/decrease if pressure is changed?

Comment: If the volume remains constant, then for an [ideal gas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_gas_law), the product of the temperature (measured from absolute zero, e.g. in Kelvin) and the pressure should be constant.

Answer (score 4):

I think there is a relationship between pressure, temperature and volume (if my memory of high school chemistry serves me correctly - confirmed by [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas_laws)):

$$T=\frac{PV}{kN}$$

$$\begin{array} \\
P=\text{Pressure} \\
V=\text{Volume} \\
k=\text{Boltzman's constant}\\
N=\text{Number of molecules}\\
T=\text{Temperature}
\end{array}
$$

Note that this is an approximate relation [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_gas) shows some more complex ways of modeling pressure on temperature.  The principle would be the same as below, just different (harder) equations.  To remind us that this is the information, an $I$ will be put as part of the conditions.

Now you have some data on part of this equation, but I'm sure you would also have some less precise information on Volume.  If you were to take the logarithm of both sides, you get:

$$log(T)=log(P)+log(V)-log(k)-log(N)$$

A very simple procedure is to assume that the volume and number of molecules is approximately a constant, and thus we can model this part as a normal distribution.  So we have:

$$log(T_{i})=log(P_{i})-log(k)+n_{i}$$

Where we assume $n_{i}\sim N(\mu,\sigma)$.  You can look at the noise level estimate $\sigma$ to decide if its worthwhile in getting a more complex model.  So this model has two parameters which you need to estimate.

So you have a new starting pressure $P_{old}$ and  starting temperature $T_{old}$ and the pressure then changes to $P_{new}=P_{old}(1+\delta_{P})$, with a corresponding change in temperature $T_{new}=T_{old}(1+\delta_{T})$.  You want the probability that $-1<\delta_{T}<0$.  Note that this would be conditional on $I$, that you are making predictions in similar Volumes and number of molecules to that which was present when you took the data.  The golden rule is to calculate this probability, conditional on what you know, integrating or averaging over what you don't know.  I'll add more details later.

**MORE DETAILS**

Any $T_{new}$ will be greater than $T_{old}$ when $log(T_{new})>log(T_{old})$, substituting in the model equation and simplifying gives:

$$log(1+\delta_{P})>n_{old}-n_{new}$$

Thus we require the probability 
$$P(log(1+\delta_{P})>n_{old}-n_{new}|n_{1},\dots,n_{N},I)$$

Fitting the model is a straight forward exercise.  You may have reasonable prior knowledge about, but since you have lots of data, it isn't necessary and a non-informative prior will do fine.  This is $p(\mu,\sigma|I)\propto\frac{1}{\sigma}$.  And the likelihood of the data is just the probability that the noise will make up the difference:

$$p(n_{1},\dots,n_{N}|\mu,\sigma,I)\propto\frac{1}{\sigma^{N}}exp\left(-\frac{\sum_{i}n_{i}^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}\right)=\frac{1}{\sigma^{N}}exp\left(-\frac{\sum_{i}\left(d_{i}-\mu\right)^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}\right)$$
Where
$$d_{i}=log\left[\frac{T_{i}k}{P_{i}}\right]$$

Now you will only need 3 numbers from your data in this solution, the sample size, $N$, the mean of $d_{i}$ denoted by $\overline{d}=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i}d_{i}$, and its standard deviation, $s_{d}^{2}=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i}(d_{i}-\overline{d})^{2}=\overline{d^{2}}-\overline{d}^{2}$.  The posterior predictive distribution for the noise is given by:

$$p(n_{old},n_{new}|N,\overline{d},s_{d}^{2},I)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}p(n_{old},n_{new}|\mu,\sigma,I)p(n_{1},\dots,n_{N}|\mu,\sigma,I)p(\mu,\sigma|I)d\mu d\sigma$$
$$=St_{2}\left(\begin{pmatrix}n_{new}\\n_{old}\end{pmatrix}|\begin{pmatrix}\overline{d}\\\overline{d}\end{pmatrix},\frac{s_{d}^{2}}{N-1}\begin{pmatrix} N+1 & 1\\ 1 & N+1 \end{pmatrix},N-1\right)$$

where $St(x|\mu,\Sigma,\nu)$ is a [bivariate student distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_Student_distribution) with location $\mu$, scatter matrix $\Sigma$, and $\nu$ degrees of freedom.  Now we simply integrate over the region that we want the probability

$$P(log(1+\delta_{P})>n_{old}-n_{new}|n_{1},\dots,n_{N},I)$$
$$=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{log(1+\delta_{P})+t}St_{2}\left(\begin{pmatrix}t\\s\end{pmatrix}|\begin{pmatrix}\overline{d}\\\overline{d}\end{pmatrix},\frac{s_{d}^{2}}{N-1}\begin{pmatrix} N+1 & 1\\ 1 & N+1 \end{pmatrix},N-1\right)dsdt$$

This integral can be done using the t-tables, but at the moment I can't remember exactly how to do it.  You get an 1-D integral over a regularised incomplete beta function.

Comment: Let me put it this way, I am working on safety Systems. I wanna calculate each term in Bayes'rule: P(Temp|Pressure)= P(Pressure|Temp)* P(Temp) / P(Pressure). I wanna use MATLAB. This Bayesian Network is assumed to be used to predict accidents in as Nuclear, Natural gas, etc. How to calculate the prior, likelihood and evidence

Answer (score 2):

Relationships between physical quantities (like pressure and temperature) often may be described using functions or equations, and sometimes the measurement error is small – this might be the case here as well. If so you could derive the type of relationship and the specific function from physics knowledge you could use statistical (including Bayesian) techniques to determine the values and uncertainties of the parameters.

If the error is large the relationship between the variables will be less apparent and (compared to the physical equation behind the phenomenon) a more simple function could be fitted on the data. Linear regression is a widely used, simple method.

You tagged your question “machine-learning”, so the relationship between your variables may be more complex, but you may not be able to derive it from physics. In this case you can choose from a wide spectrum of non-linear machine learning and statistical techniques.

In any case I suggest you to plot your data using a scatterplot, think about the possible mechanisms between the variables. Although machine learning can be Bayesian, too, the best Bayesian approach may be fitting plausible models on the data.

Comment: Thank you so much. I wanna calculate each term in Bayes'rule: P(Temp|Pressure)= P(Pressure|Temp)* P(Temp) / P(Pressure). I wanna use MATLAB. This Bayesian Network is assumed to be used to predict accidents in as Nuclear system, Natural gas, etc. How to calculate the prior, likelihood and evidence. I wanna know what is the probability that Temp will change if pressure changes